# Plugging in external harddrive freezes filesystem

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, filesystems, freeze

When I plug in my external harddrive (like 8 years old), the file system freezes. It registers on the computer but when I open the file explorer on my system it just doesn't load ever (even on folders on my computer). If I boot my computer with the external hard drive plugged in, my graphics doesn't load. I can see system notices, some applications but the rest is completely black. When plugged into another computer the file system doesn't crash but loading the contents of the harddrive takes several minutes (if it even loads). What can be the issue and how do I solve it?

Correction: On the second computer it doesn't load the files on the harddrive progressbar stuck at 99%

[image]

S.M.A.R.T values:

Comment: Does the external HDD has an own power supply? If a hard disks "freezes" the system often the HDD is defect and tries to read each sector which fails so it is read again and again and again...

Comment: It does have an external power supply. I havent touched it since the last time it worked. Can it go defect just like that? How can I fix it? @Robert

Comment: If Windows is still responsive try to get the SMART values of the disk e.g. using [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/). Potentially the disk will have defect sectors or other problems.

Comment: This is the numbers using HDDscan @Robert https://i.imgur.com/edCr9aV.png

Comment: The two values with exclamation mark are a strong indicator that the HDD is near to death.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use it too much unless you wanna risk loosing the data. Make an HD image (you don't have to mount the file system, just make a sector by sector image and hope there is still s.th. to recover). Having the image on a working HD you can start the recovery process. With luck mounting the file system directly will work right away.

Comment: Okay I see. I wonder how this happened though. I've only used it a total of 5 times (meaning plugged in and out).

Comment: maybe just bad luck...  s.t. this happens... it was probable bad from the beginning and now it passed a certain threshold